# getting error :AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python-3.x

this is my code:

```
urls = [] 
uni_names = [] 
page_urls_new = [] 
university_details = ["Name","Link","Location","Rank"]

#Determine 
#Colleges 

start_time = int(round(time.time())) 

for i in range(0, len(page_urls)): 
    page_url = page_urls[i] 
    page_text_soup = BeautifulSoup(extract_source(page_url), "lxml") 
    entries = int(page_text_soup.find('strong', attrs={'data-test-id': 'total-items'}).text) 
    entries = int((entries / 20) + (0 if 0 == entries % 20 else 1))
```

Comment: It would be better if you `format` your code, so we can understand it. Also, provide more details of what's happening, and what did you expect to do.

Answer (score 2):

Formatted the code on my side and you get this error because:

```
page_text_soup.find('strong', attrs={'data-test-id': 'total-items'})
```

returns `None` in your case, so when you try to access `text` attribute it will raise the attribute error.

Make sure the text you search for is present in your data, or enclose that line in a `try/except` block to handle this type of scenario.